# Which steps could you take to minimize the effect of a potential (D)DoS attack in IIS?

Tags: iis, ddos

With a single-server setup for simplicity, which steps could you do to minimize the attacks of a (D)DoS attack? And is it really worth it taking these steps, considering their effectivity and impact on 'normal' users?

[EDIT] I also meant to include steps which you would need inject into your code to apply, not only IIS setup.

Comment: Yeay, I read the question again, and saw it was typed as it was a SF question. That wasn't really what I meant though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good point to start it´s having a good firewall that blocks IP when they are doing a lot of petitions per second.

The IIS LockDown Tool can be useful: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd450372(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

-- Identifying the expected number of users/connection and limiting the connection.
-- URLScan can filter out unwanted requests.. search for URLScan on iis.net

:)